# Disable Button after Click whilst maintaining CausesValidation and an OnClick-Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, button, postback

So I've got this button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" meta:resourcekey="btnSubmit" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

meta:resourcekey is for Localization Resources, doesn't concern us here - as we can see it has got an OnClick-Method and causes Validation.

That works fine, too, but I'd like to disable that button after the user clicked it so he/she can't click it multiple times before the PostBack succeeds, so here's what I did in `Page_Load`:

```
btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" +
        Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, "").ToString());
```

onclick I'm disabling the button and re-adding the PostBackReference necessary for the OnClick-Method.

Problem: CausesValidation is gone, sadface. How exactly would I re-add that in CodeBehind or alternatively - What's an entirely different solution to this?

My Button has to:

a) disable itself after clicking, yet be enabled after the postback
b) have an OnClick CodeBehind Method
c) cause Validation

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just override the Onload event of ur page or master page with

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
   // prevents form from being submitted multiple times in MOST cases
   // programatic client-side calls to __doPostBack() can bypass this
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(), "ServerForm",
    "if (this.submitted) return false; this.submitted = true; return true;");
}
```

Comment: Works nicely, also by far the leanest idea, I don't need to disable the button and Validation/Onclick work regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in Page_Load

### VB

```
Dim postBackOptions As PostBackOptions = New PostBackOptions(btnSubmit)
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "this.disabled=true;"
btnSubmit.OnClientClick += ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptionClaim)
```

### C#

```
PostBackOptions postBackOptions = new PostBackOptions(btnSubmit);
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "this.disabled=true;";
btnSubmit.OnClientClick += ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptionClaim);
```

Comment: Nevermind, that works now -

Next problem: Page is not valid, Button click is fired, Button validates page, Validators throw their ErrorTexts, all is well - except that the button stays disabled because no PostBack was raised.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*

```
if(Page_ClientValidate()) {this.visibility='hidden';}
```

If you need to have server side validation before you know whether to hide/disable the button or not you'll probably want to forgo the disabling of the button and just make sure your server-side code doesn't execute more than necessary if a user hammers on the button.

You could put a hidden field and generate a GUID for it in the page_load if(!IsPostBack) then on your btnSubmit_click do something like

```
if(Session[Page.ToString() + "_spam"] != null && Session[Page.ToString() + "_spam"] == hdnGuid.Value) { 
    return 
} else { 
    Session[Page.ToString() + "_spam"] = hdnGuid.Value; 
    //do stuff 
}
```

Comment: How would that solve my problem? Yes, clearly that would work just as well as disabling, but it's still something that I need to activate onclick.

Comment: @Dennis Röttger - You want to hide the button only if everything is valid so use the Page_ClientValidate() to check before hand if everything is correct.