# asp.net Disable Button after Click while maintaining CausesValidation and an OnClick-Method

Tags: c#, asp.net

**.aspx**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvite" Width="170px" Height="20px" runat="server" 
                          Font-Size="Small" ></asp:TextBox>

                          <AjaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="tbexInvite" 
                          runat="server" SkinID="skinTextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                          TargetControlID="txtInvite" WatermarkText="Email"></AjaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInvite" runat="server" 
                          Display="None" ValidationGroup="Inivitation" SetFocusOnError="true" 
                          ControlToValidate="txtInvite" ErrorMessage="Enter Email."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExpInvite" runat="server" 
                          Display="None" ValidationGroup="Inivitation" SetFocusOnError="true" 
                          ValidationExpression="\s*\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*" 
                          ControlToValidate="txtInvite" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

 <div  class="ButtonLogin" style="margin-top:-27px;margin-right:143px;_margin-right:105px;">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
                          <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnInvite" runat="server" CssClass="cssLoginButton blue" Text="Invite" ToolTip="Invite" ValidationGroup="Inivitation" CausesValidation="true" onclick="btnInvite_Click" />

                          </ContentTemplate>
                       </asp:UpdatePanel>
                 </div>
                      <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" DisplayAfter="0">
                           <ProgressTemplate>
                                  <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Lifetrons/images/progressbar.gif" AlternateText="Processing" runat="server" />
                           </ProgressTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Page_load Code

**.CS**

```
this.btnInvite.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.btnInvite, "").ToString());
```

I want to disable button after clicking on it with maintaining validation and Onlick method. I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521253/disable-button-after-click-whilst-maintaining-causesvalidation-and-an-onclick-me) my problem is same like this question but I haven't solve my problem. How can I solve?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `OnLoad`?

Comment: @SergeBelov yes I have tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to mess around with your code-behind Page_Load event. In your button control, just add the following snippet:

```
OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate('Inivitation')){this.disabled=true;}"
```

So that your button looks like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInvite" runat="server" CssClass="cssLoginButton blue" Text="Invite"
ToolTip="Invite" ValidationGroup="Inivitation" CausesValidation="true"
onclick="btnInvite_Click" OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate('Inivitation')){this.disabled=true;}" />
```

Comment: Actually I have two usercontrol pages i.e. **.ascx** on login page.  first is **Login.ascx** and another is **Invitation.ascx**. Login page contains two text box with validation,One login button and Invitation page containts one text box with validation,One invite button. I change my code according to your suggestion. If I click  on login button it show validation of invitation text box or if I click on button Invite it show validation of login page. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to change whats inside Page_ClientValidate to the correct ValidationGroup.

The code I gave was based on your invite button. What is the validation group of your login button?

Comment: Thank for replay I have changed validation group accorind to that page. validation group is **UserLogin**

Comment: Problem solve thank you for help. I have just added UseSubmitBehavior="false"

Comment: Warning. This solution disables autocomplete functionality on the whole page !!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the button using the Button_Click method.  Make your first line something like this:

```
Button.Enabled = False;
```

There is a problem with this method though.  If the page loads too quickly or the code freezes it will not disable the button properly.  Just remember to re-enable the button at the end of the method if the validation fails or times out.

Another method you may try is to hide it using CSS.  I am a big fan of this because it always works and it is very simple.  You need a technology like jQuery where you can add classes on the fly.  You can use the AddClass and RemoveClass API in jQuery to add/remove CSS classes at runtime.  Take a look here.  http://jqueryui.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

you can use Like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInvite" runat="server" CssClass="cssLoginButton blue" Text="Invite" ToolTip="Invite" ValidationGroup="Inivitation" CausesValidation="true" UseSubmitBehavior = False"onclick="btnInvite_Click" />
```