# ASP.NET Client-side validation on textbox without postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and would like to do the following on client side because I do not want the page to reload (do not want postback). I would like to check for user input with following conditions:

1. There are 2 radiobuttons and 2 textboxes and 1 button. Something like this:
   [image]
2. User must tick the radiobutton in order to activate the textbox (textboxes by default is disabled)
3. If user tick radiobutton 1, textbox1 will be activated and textbox2 will be empty and disabled, if user press the button and textbox1 is empty message1 will activate.
4. Same goes to the second radiobutton and textbox2.

### Edit

I noticed that my button is in `<asp:button>` and not `<input type="submit>` therefore it will run my code behind to valdiate at server. Correct me if I am wrong. So how do I make my `<asp:button>` to validate user input without have to pass to server?

Comment: Can you provide me the code?

Comment: My button is <asp:Button class="mybtn" ID="btn1"  runat="server" Text="Submit" /> not <input type="submit">

Comment: @TanSiongZhe I think that the question is: "How do I validade only the text box associated with the selected radiobutton?", Am I correct?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Yes absolutely. So do I need to change my title?

Comment: I think it is a good idea... because people understood something else, as you can see by looking at previous comments... or you can explain this in the question itself to make it clearer.

Comment: I've made my amendment. Hope to get some feedback soon :)

Comment: Do you need help with the validation or help with how to toggle the state of the text boxes? I assume you want to validate that there is text in the text box when the radio button is checked?

Comment: @JonP Yes I want to do both but on client side without postback because postback will refresh my page.

Comment: @TanSiongZhe Do you need any more help with this or has one of the answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try:

```
<asp:button onClientClick="return validateData();">
```

And in the JavaScript it should be:

```
function validateData() {
    if (OK) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`return true` will make your page be posted back to the server, and `return false` will prevent your page from doing that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

Handling the validation, I would use ASP.net  custom validators and use jquery to assis with the client side validation:

**ASP.net aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="requiedCheck1" class="check">
           <asp:RadioButton ID="radio1" runat="server" GroupName="myGroup" />
           <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server" Disabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:CustomValidator
               ID="val1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Text" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateSomething" ControlToValidate="text1" ValidateEmptyText="true" ></asp:CustomValidator>
        </div>
        <div id="requiedCheck2" class="check">
           <asp:RadioButton ID="radio2" runat="server" GroupName="myGroup" />
           <asp:TextBox ID="text2" runat="server" Disabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:CustomValidator
               ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Text" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateSomething" ControlToValidate="text2" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
        </div>
        <asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="Button" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Note that I have set `ValidateEmptyText` to `true`.

**js Validation function**

```
function ValidateSomething(sender, args) {

        args.IsValid = false;
        var parentDiv = $(sender).parent(".check");

        var radioChecked = $(parentDiv).find("input:radio").is(":checked");
        var hasText = $(parentDiv).find("input:text").val().length > 0;



        if (radioChecked) {
            args.IsValid = hasText;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }

    }
```

I would also add a server-side validation method too.

If you want to get really fancy you should be able to wire up the radio buttons too. This will fire the validation when the radiobuttons are checked

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Wire up the radio buttons to trigger validation this is optional
    $(".check input:radio").each(function () {
        ValidatorHookupControlID($(this).attr('id'), document.getElementById("<%= val1.ClientID %>"));
        ValidatorHookupControlID($(this).attr('id'), document.getElementById("<%= val2.ClientID %>"));
    }); 

    //jquery to change the disabled state
    $(".check :radio").click(function(){
        var parDiv = $(this).parent(".check"); //get parent div
        //empty text and set all to disabled
        $(".check input:text").val("").prop("disabled", true);

        //set target to enabled
        $(parDiv).find("input:text").prop("disabled", false);
     });           
});
```

I've added the jQuery javascript to toggle the disabled state of the text boxes. You can see the toggle in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/cVACb/

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery for your purpose :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Error = false;
        $("#RadioButton1").click(function () {
            $("#TextBox2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#TextBox1").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
        $("#RadioButton2").click(function () {
            $("#TextBox1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#TextBox2").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            var TextBox1value = $("#TextBox1").val();
            var TextBox2value = $("#TextBox2").val();
            var TextBox1Disable = $("#TextBox1").attr("disabled");
            var TextBox2Disable = $("#TextBox2").attr("disabled");

            if ((TextBox1value == "") && TextBox1Disable != "disabled") {
                $("#Label1").text("text can not be empty");
                Error = true;
            }
            if ((TextBox2value == "") && TextBox2Disable != "disabled") {
                $("#Label2").text("text can not be empty");
                Error = true;
            }

        });


        $("#form1").submit(function (e) {
            if (Error) {
                alert("there are Some validation error in your page...!");
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

body elements are :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="g1" /><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="g1" /><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button control, just add the following snippet:

```
OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate(ValidateSomething)){this.disabled=true;}"
```

Check this link [asp.net Disable Button after Click while maintaining CausesValidation and an OnClick-Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541229/asp-net-disable-button-after-click-while-maintaining-causesvalidation-and-an-onc)

Answer (score 0):

Would adding a validationgroup to your validator as well as the button you where trying to use as the trigger to check for validation?

Validation groups are really easy to use once you get the hang of them. I wont go diving into too many details about validators but if the information would be helpful I can always add it to the post. Hope you had resolved your answer.