# disabling button after one click to prevent multiple submissions, enabling after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have and ASP button that when its clicked a trouble ticket is created. Sometimes the process takes a few seconds and the end user presses submit button multiple times generating duplicate tickets. Once the submission is successful it redirects to another page saying "blah blah blah her is your ticket number" what i'd like to happen is the button to change to something like "please wait" and disabling the multiple clicks till they are redirected to another page. Also when the page is reloaded later that the button is no longer disabled. Im using field validators and was thinking of using brute force by clearing text boxes after submit click so that required field validators picked up the empty fields and wouldn't allow extra clicks but don't know if fields would clear quick enough?

```
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Request"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="" />
```

Im not very familiar with javascript, fresh out of school and just got into the field after career change. So thanks for your patience in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Button after Click whilst maintaining CausesValidation and an OnClick-Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521253/disable-button-after-click-whilst-maintaining-causesvalidation-and-an-onclick-me)

Comment: The top answer to this question uses my favorite technique [Simplest way to disable button on submission of a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529836/simplest-way-to-disable-button-on-submission-of-a-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some simple javascript like this:

`<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Request"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="disableButton" />`

```
<script> 
  function disableButton(){ document.getElementById('<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').disabled = true; }
</script>
```